# compiling ffmpeg with libvpx, unable to find decoder

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, msys2, yasm, libvpx

I am trying to compile ffmpeg with libvpx support on Windows with Visual Studio compiler.

I am using msys2 for building platform and running flowing commands for libvpx

```
cd libvpx
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --target=x86_64-win64-vs16 --as=yasm
make
make install
```

then adding path file and compiling ffmpeg

```
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" 
./configure --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86_64 \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs=-lpthread \
  --extra-libs=-lm \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-libvpx
```

When I run the command above, I get the errror :

```
libvpx enabled but no supported decoders found
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the configure log in `ffbuild/config.log` to see the exact reason why it fails.

My educated guess is that you're mixing-up the Visual Studio C [runtime library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170).

By default `libvpx` uses the multithread, DLL-specific version of the runtime (`/MD`), while `ffmpeg` uses the multithreaded, static version (`/MT`).

Configure `libvpx` to use `/MT`:

```
./configure \
    --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build"
    --target=x86_64-win64-vs17 \
    --enable-static-msvcrt \
    --disable-examples \
    --disable-unit-tests \
    --as=yasm
```